# Exporting to Runnable jar with extra native code libraries in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jri, java.library.path

I am having trouble exporting my java project from eclipse as a jar executable file. My java project uses an external library (its called jri). I have exported the jri.jar file and set the library path for its native library in eclipse, and it works great in development in eclipse. However, when I export it as an executable jar file I get the following error:

```
Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.
```

I have placed a folder called lib in the same directory as my project's jar; this lib folder contains jri's native library. jri's native library is not in one file but in a folder. This is the same setup I have in eclipse.

The way I am exporting my project in eclipse is

```
Export...
Java > Runnable JAR file
Copy required libraries into a sub folder next to the generated Jar
Finish
```

And my folder is organized like this

```
folder project
  project.jar
  project_lib
    jri.jar
    jri native library folder
```

The MANIFEST.MF of my project.jar is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: . project_lib/jri.jar
Main-Class: index
```

What I want to achieve is to give another person a folder including project.jar and anything else needed so she/he can run it without needing to install anything else.
Thanks so much

Comment: If you hate dont use it, dont blame about it. If something goes wrong with eclipse it might be your fault not eclipse.

Comment: Check this similar answer, it migth help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702132/how-can-i-include-platform-specific-native-libraries-in-the-jar-file-using-ecli

Comment: Did you try adding project_lib/jri_native_library_folder to the manifest.mf classpath?

Comment: @KJP I am going to try that now

Comment: @KJP I didnt get any better results, I think it is because the problem is in the library path and not in the class path

Comment: What's wrong with using ANT? In the time of your running bounty, you could have written your build.xml file which does what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a script containing something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Djava.library.path=project_lib/native/ -jar project_lib/jri.jar
```

I export some java projects that way.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively hard to implement. The solutions I have seen involve extracting the native libraries in the JAR to an OS temp directory and then loading it. I would go for an integrated solution for that. [One Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) and [Java Class Loader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) support it, and on the second page you will find links to similar tools.

Comment: You're right, as far as I know, Java cannot load JNI libraries (.dll, .so, etc.) from a JAR file. The solutions you mention extract the relevant files at runtime, so that Java can load them.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the libraries **inside** your jar:

> Export...
>
> Java > Runnable JAR file
>
> Package required libraries into generated Jar
>
> Finish

I always export this way.
I don't know if it will work in your case, but worth a try.

---

**Edit:**

See these links:

- [Instalation, setup and setting environment properly](http://binfalse.de/2011/02/talking-r-through-java/)
- [What to do when getting *Cannot find JRI native library!*](http://blog.pingoured.fr/index.php?post/2009/03/23/Getting-rJava/JRI-to-work%3a)

My guess is that this have something to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH not correctly been set. Or the file wich it is searching for isn't in the path listed.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesnt work, remember that the native libraries for the external package is in a folder and the java.library.path need to have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You know I had the similar problems

```
Could not extract native JNI library.
```

all above proposes can't help me. I couldn't stop and start gradle deamon by using follow command:

```
gradle --stop
```

I saw that gradle deamon still not stopped in my processes. That's why I kill it in my process and all will be fine :)